# Why all websites are going for HTTPS

Tags: http, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

Having a HTTPS is good for websites, if there is any confidential data is handled.

But now-a-days even, Content management sites too having the Https.

Is there any reason behind it.

Any kind of advantage (like security or related to search optimization etc.) will we get, if a normal (static content/dynamic content) website is having the Https.

Could some one share some input in this.

Answer (score 0):

Google has taken a strict stance to ensure that it protects the privacy of their consumers. Security, they say, has always been “a top priority” for them.
[Here's What Is the Overall HTTPS SEO Impact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvf9k.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting HTTP over SSL not only secures traffic, but it tells your browser that the site you're visiting has been verified by a Certificate Authority.

You browser has a store containing the public keys of all the Certificate Authorities it trusts. When you visit a HTTPS site, the SSL certificate states which Certificated Authority issued their cert.

Your browser uses the public key of that Certificate Authority to try and decrypt the certificate. If this works - the site can be trusted.